# excel VBA error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Tags: vba, excel

It seems a normal question and I have searched and tried many suggestions here but the error persists. I want to copy a "case1" sheet from current workbook to an existing workbook(file name is "workbook2.xlsx", it has a worksheet named "case2"), then save the workbook and close it. Sometimes it works well, but most of the time I kept getting the same error. In fact I did not change any code so I don't know where went wrong.

The error shows "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients". It always breaks in the same place:

> `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("case1").Copy Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Case2")`

```
Sub CopySheet()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False



    'open existing "workbook2.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open filename:="c:\workbook2.xlsx"

    'copy a sheet named "case1" from current workbook to "workbook2.xlsx" which already has a sheet named "case2"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("case1").Copy Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Case2")

    'close "workbook2.xlsx"
    Workbooks("workbook2.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Always set references to sheets and workbooks, then there is no chance of confusing which is which. This code does the same thing and should not give you any errors.

```
Sub CopySheet()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet 'Source
    Dim wb2 As Workbook, ws2 As Worksheet   'Target

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("case1")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("c:\workbook2.xlsx")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("case2")

    ws1.Copy Before:=ws2
    wb2.Close True
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot!   My problem was solved based on your suggestion!