# VBA throwing "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients" error

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a VBA macro in Excel quite a while back that was working flawlessly for months. Suddenly, the other day it started throwing an error, though I had not made any changes to the workbook:

> Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
>
> Automation error
>
> The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

I traced the error to the following lines of code.

```
wkbTool.Worksheets("Excl Spine").Range("A2:D" & exclRow).ClearContents '<--- RUNS GREAT
wkbTool.Worksheets("Delq Spine").Range("C2:D13").ClearContents '<--- ERROR OCCURS HERE
```

Note that the **first** line runs fine every time and the **second** line is where the error occurs. I point this out because they are doing roughly the same types of work, but one throws the error while the other doesn't. This isn't my first reference to `wkbTool.Worksheets("Delq Spine")` in the script.

---

I'm [aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065262/excel-vba-error-the-object-invoked-has-disconnected-from-its-clients) that [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302918/excel-vba-automation-error-the-object-invoked-has-disconnected-from-its-clients) for [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1062608/the-object-invoked-has-disconnected-from-its-clients) error [abound](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=83218). I've tried most of them and a few ideas of my own. For example, the following throws the same error:

**Attempt 1 - Everything is a variable**

```
Dim wkbTool as Workbook
Dim wksht as Worksheet
Dim myRange as Range

Set wkbTool = Workbooks("Name.xlsm")
Set wksht = wkbTool.Worksheets("Delq Spine")
Set myRange = wksht.Range("C2:D13")

myRange.ClearContents '<--- ERROR
```

**Attempt 2 - The opposite**

```
Workbooks("Name.xlsm").Worksheets("Delq Spine").Range("C2:D13").ClearContents
```

**Attempt 3 - Perhaps `ClearContents` doing something crazy, skip it**

```
For i = 3 to 4
    For j = 2 to 13
        wkbTool.Worksheets("Delq Spine").cells(j,i) = ""
    Next j
Next i
```

This results in Excel crashing, though it does **not** throw the error first. It clearly performs the operation in the first iteration before crashing because, when Excel recovers the workbook, cell(2,3) is empty. Also, I am not using `ClearContents` for the first line in this attempt, just in case `ClearContents` is causing something in itself.

**Attempt 4 - Fine, I don't need that line anyway**

I comment out the line that is causing the error. Upon looping back the next time, there is a reference to `Worksheets("Delq Spine")` that works in the first iteration but not the second:

```
With wkbTool.Worksheets("Delq Spine")
        .Activate
        .Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[" & wkbNew.Name & "]" & wksht.Name & "'!R3C2:R14C3,2,FALSE),0)"
End With
```

In the above, the worksheet is activated, but Excel crashes similar to Attempt 3 when assigning the formula to C2. Again, once Excel recovers, it's clear that the operation was successful, as the formula is updated in that cell.

**Attempt 5 - Surely the workbook has been corrupted**

I went back through my company's backup files to find a version of the workbook that was definitely working at the time. It ran in to the same error at the same place.

**Attempt 6 - Let's just recreate the workbook then**

I recreated the workbook from scratch, including writing in all formulas and formatting the cells. I did copy/paste the VBA script to the new version because I don't have time to rewrite it all only for it to fail again.

---

I will continue to add more information about attempts I made as I think of them, I've been working on this problem on and off for the last week.

Comment: Does the worksheet `"Delq Spine"` have event handlers? Do some of its cells have data validation? Protection? do you use `.Activate` and `.Select` frequently in the code? There are so many potential causes for this anomaly, you need to check them one by one. Difficult to diagnose by anyone else without some minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You can also try disabling events, screen updating, all possible stuff at the beginning of the macro.

Comment: @A.S.H, thanks for the tips. I do have events and screen updating disabled. There are no event handlers, data validation, or protection on the worksheet. Unfortunately, I do have a couple instances of `.Activate` and `.Select`, some of which would be easy to replace. I can't imagine that would be the cause though, since it was working fine until recently (with no changes being made). I'll just have to spend some time replacing those Activations and Selections.

Comment: @A.S.H, if that fails, I will see about stripping out as much as possible while still having the the script run and fail. It's too long to post here in raw form. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, those lines where the code breaks are really too simple to be suspect. There's surely something going on elsewhere.

Comment: An error will occur if at least one cell in the range to be cleared is merged with a cell outside the range.